# onfocuschangelistener is not responding for all audio manager changes

Tags: android, audio, onchange

I asked a Question in following link [how to know when audio is started playing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783031/how-to-know-when-audio-is-started-playing-in-android/10783453#comment14024396_10783453)
I got a perfect answer. I attached code of it. Now my problem is when music starts playing i get audio focus loss . and my `onfocuschange` listener not responding for the changes in audio manager. Is there any thing wrong in my code . So than i can listen to all changes (start ,pause, stop)in audio manager. thanks for help.

I implemented it in my service class.

```
am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    am.getMode();

      afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {


            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                Log.d("new","focus: " +focusChange+"mode "+am.getMode() +"ismusic "+am.isMusicActive());


                if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT){
                    Log.d("new","focus:started trans " );

                }else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK){
                    Log.d("new","focus:started duck " );

                }

            else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){
                   Log.d("new","focus:paused  " );
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                Log.d("new","focus:started " );
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                    Log.d("new","focus:stoped  " );
                   // am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
                   // am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
                    // Stop playback
                }
            }
        };
```